# Eclipse: unrecognized option '-pthread'

Tags: c, eclipse, multithreading, gcc, pthreads

I'm new programming in C, now I'm trying to implement threads in a motor control program I am developing but my problem is that I can not run the `pthread.h` library in eclipse. despite haver installed POSIX threading library for Win32

Info: Internal Builder is used for build

```
gcc -O3 -g3 -Wall -pthread -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\main.o ..\src\main.c 
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-pthread'
Info: Parallel threads used: 1
```

Even though I'm just stating nothing but the library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image]

check forum several times and did what they wanted to establish in the `-pthread` miscellaneous and link phtread but I can not solve the problem, could someone please help me?

I have Windows 10, 64 bits.

Comment: This has pretty little to do with Eclipse itself, but everything with GCC and how you install the POSIX threads library for MS Windows. Just a guess: The `-pthread` option is only for proper POSIX systems while on MS Windows it's just a library, which you link with `-l<name of the library>`. That said, you say you're new to C. Starting with cross-platform hacks for POSIX threading might be one task too many for a beginner. Either run your experiments on a real POSIX system or stay within the win32 API, which also provides its own, native threading support.

Comment: I'm new to C but I've programmed in VHDL and C ++ if I need to create processes for the simultaneous handling step for a CNC machine motors and is 3 PWM outputs must be independent of each but are handled by a function main within the code, as there may be a more facul way to implement something like this.

Note: I do not eclipse loaded but CodeWarrior where pthread program my Blast (KL25Z) if I load the library.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having big problems understanding this reply of yours, as there's way too much information crammed in those two sentences.

Comment: Please recompile in verbose mode, `gcc -v -O3 -g3 -Wall -pthread -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\main.o ..\src\main.c` and post the complete output in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

**If your code is not compiling**, you need to add `-pthread` argument in your `gcc` compilation as follows.

1. **Navigate to:** Project -> Properties
2. **On the left:** c/c++ build -> GCC C Compiler -> Miscellaneous
3. **Add `-pthread` argument** at the beginning `Other Flags` section
4. **Also pthread library**  add c/c++ build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Libraries
5. And include pthread library into other libraries.
6. Click apply.
7. Clean and build the project.

If you have only **Unresolved inclusion** problem alone then specify the file system path for the `pthread.h` as your compiler does not know this.
[Check here how to add pthread.h in your filesystem](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm).

Comment: You could show me with pictures how add the patch, i tried manytimes how you sayed, but I can not solve the problem.

Comment: This can't work, as the `-pthread` flag is already present (see the error message), but the win32(!) compiler obviously doesn't understand it, as it has no native pthreads implementation on this platform. So, step 3 is probably wrong and should be skipped. Concerning the rest, what exactly is the problem, Julian? Can't you follow these steps or do they not bring the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying, resort to the use of counters card that I use (KL25Z) and events programming.